# Inheritance problems with constructrors

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have three classes.  The base class is called `Jet`:

```
class Jet
{
public :
    Jet(int fuel);
    void fly();

protected:
    int mfuel;
};

Jet::Jet(int fuel): mfuel(fuel) {}
```

The second class is called `F16`:

```
class F16 : public Jet
{
public:
    F16(int fuel, int numMissiles);
    void fireMissile();

protected:
    int mNumMissles;
};

F16::F16(int fuel, int numMissiles): Jet(fuel), mNumMissles(numMissiles) {}
```

A third class `B18` inherits everything normally from `F16`:

```
class B18 : public F16
{
public:
    B18(int fuel, int numMissiles, int bullets);
    void fireBullets();

private:
    int mBullets;

};
```

Now my question is is there a way in the member member initializer here :

```
B18::B18(int fuel, int numMissiles, int bullets) :
        F16(fuel, numMissiles), mBullets(bullets) {}
```

...so i can just erase `int fuel` from `B18`, and inherit only the `numMissiles` from `F16`? For example:

```
B18::B18(int numMissiles, int bullets) :
        F16(numMissiles), mBullets(bullets) {}
```

Something like the above *(which of course doesn't work, and probably has logical errors)*.

Comment: I don't understand "smthg" or "ofc". Could you replace those with complete words?

Comment: I understand this is a contrived example, but from a design perspective, a `B18` is not an `F16`. Both should inherit from `Jet`. Perhaps describe the real problem you're solving.

Comment: @DarkFalcon - The [B18](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-18_Bolo) wasn't even a jet. It was a propeller-driven DC-2.

Comment: Ofc& Ofcourse , Smthg& something

Comment: @Robᵩ: Shows you how much I pay attention. :)

Comment: The thing that i was experimenting if there is a possibility to initialize just a part of F16 to the b18 like just the numMussiles part and not the fuel also from the constructor...in short words to choose what i want to inherit in the member initializator

Comment: @RedFox: Why not add *another* constructor in `F16` so you can choose which constructor to use in the derived class based on what you want to initialize?

Comment: @Nawaz Something like overloading with contructors? like two constructors one which had numMissles and the other one which has fuel and numMussles?

Comment: @RedFox - Thank you for the explanation. Stack Overflow has readers of various degrees of familiarity with English. Many of them have distinct colloquial idioms. Please use complete words and sentences with appropriate punctuation if you are able to do so.

Comment: @RedFox: Sure, you can overload constructors.  It works pretty much the same as overloading other functions.

Comment: Why do you even need inheritance here?  You don;t have any virtual functions.  What is the reason for the abstraction and in what circumstances will you benefit from type erasure?

Comment: You also do not have a virtual destructor for the Jet class.  Read Effective C++ and More Effective C++ before writing another line of code.

Comment: @RedFox: See my answer. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment gave more information about the problem. So I'm quoting here for the sake for visibility:

> The thing that i was experimenting if there is a possibility to initialize just a part of F16 to the b18 like just the numMussiles part and not the fuel also from the constructor...in short words to choose what i want to inherit in the member initializator

It looks like overloaded constructors can solve your problem. Add another constructor to your class `F16`, so you can choose appropriate constructor in the derived class based on what you want to initialize.

Here is what you can do:

```
class F16 : public Jet
{
public:
  F16(int numMissiles); //<------ add this
  F16(int fuel,int numMissiles);
  void fireMissile();

  protected:
  int mNumMissles;
};
```

then you can choose constructor based on what you want to initialize:

```
//unchanged : from your code!
B18::B18(int numMissiles,int bullets): F16(numMissiles),mBullets(bullets) {}
```

It chooses the first constructor from `F16`. Note that it is better to initialize the class fully, which means initialize every member to some [default] values (even if you don't need them for particular case).

Answer (score 2):

I'm doubtful that inheritance in that case can be completely blocked, but you did mention the member initializer line of code.  In that you should be able to just do something like this:

```
B18::B18(int numMissiles,int bullets): F16(30,numMissiles),mBullets(bullets)   {}
```

You may already know that though.  Another option would be something like this:

```
public:
    F16(int numMissiles, int fuel = 45);
```

and:

```
B18::B18(int numMissiles,int bullets): F16(numMissiles),mBullets(bullets)   {}
```

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're needing, but maybe it'll help.  Again I may be wrong about this, but I'm kind of doubtful that you can just keep a base class's variables from being set up through inheritance.  The closest thing would be to leave pointer variables uninitialized.

Comment: But is there any way without using integers at all?

Comment: Redfox, you've defined `Jet` as *requiring* an integer `fuel` argument. Unless you change `Jet` to make that argument optional, all other code that creates `Jet` instances will have to provide a value *somehow*. You can either pass the responsibility on to the callers, as your original code did, or make a default selection, as the code in this answer does.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean exactly, since you can inherit from a nonexistent value. But maybe what you're trying to do involves default parameters? So for example, you'd have:

```cpp
class Jet
{
public :
   Jet(int fuel);
   void fly();

protected:
   int mfuel;
};

Jet::Jet(int fuel): mfuel(fuel) {}

class F16 : public Jet
{
public:
   F16(int numMissiles = 10, int fuel = 20);
   void fireMissile();

protected:
   int mNumMissles;
};

F16::F16(int numMissiles, int fuel): Jet(fuel), mNumMissles(numMissiles) {}

class B18: public F16
{
public :
   B18(int bullets, int numMissiles, int fuel);
   B18(int bullets);
   void firebullets();

private:
   int mBullets;
};

B18::B18(int bullets, int numMissiles, int fuel) : F16(numMissiles, fuel), mBullets(bullets) {}
B18::B18(int bullets): F16(), mBullets(bullets) {}
```

In this way, creating a B18 object with a single int parameter will call the F16 constructor using its default parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "You can inherit from a nonexistence value" doesn't make sense. Could you please [edit] your answer to clarify or rephrase?

Comment: @RobKennedy I loosely translated that as *"Default values for arguments to constructors and methods exist, let me show you them."*.  Maybe.  :-)  But yes, welcome user2001505 - editing is a big part of the fun here.  It also helps to set your user name, and you can also [upload a personal avatar](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/) quite easily.